# Disable space character virtual keyboard iOS

Tags: objective-c, user-interface, keyboard

I want to disable the space character from the virtual keyboard on my iOS application when users edit an input text.

Users should enter a **nickname**. So I want to remove all space characters.

Thanks.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Trying to modify the standard keyboard requires taking a dangerous path into private APIs and a broken app in future iOS versions.

I think the best solution for you would be to implement the `textField:shouldChangeCharactersInRange:replacementString:` method of `UITextFieldDelegate` and replace whitespace characters with the empty string.

Once this is implemented, hitting the space bar will simply do nothing.

Comment: Yes thanks I just forgot to add the delegate method.
input.delegate = self;